# Javascript variable = function() -> undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, return-value, arrow-functions

When I run this code the log file name will be 'undefined'. the checkfile return the correct file name, but the filename variable won't be equal with that.

```
const logger = async () => {
  filename = await checkFile();
  openFile();
}

const checkFile = async () => {
  originfn = "xyservice_" + await datetime.date() + ".log";

  fs.access(`logs/${originfn}`, fs.constants.F_OK, (err) => {
    //console.log(`logs/${origfn} ${err ? 'does not exist' : 'exists'}`);
    if (err) {

      return originfn;
    } else {

      return originfn + ".2";
    }
  });
}

const openFile = async () => {
  fs.appendFile(`logs/${filename}`, await time() + `Logging system 
started...in file logs/${filename}`, function(err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);

    console.log('Log file created...');
  });

  return;
}
```

Then how is this code working? I do not understand. Whats the diffs?

```
const permParser = async (perms) => {

let permissions = {}

//general code

return permissions;
}
```

I call like this
   `await permParser(permtopars)`

Comment: Well... you definitely do not understand how to work with async/await functions, do you?

Comment: Yeah, I just got into it.

Comment: I don't think you've got the understanding of how callbacks work, you can't `return` from async callbacks.

Comment: Keyword `await` should be placed in front of async functions, such as `fs.access(...)` & `fs.appendFile(...)`

Comment: Your function doesn’t return anything, hence the default return value (‘undefined’).